# Different results OS X/Linux with "find PATH -mount \( -type f -o -type d \) -print0 | LC_ALL=C sort --zero-terminated > OUTPUT.txt"

Tags: linux, find, osx, sort, diff

this command is part of a script I use for comparing files:

```
find test/ -mount \( -type f -o -type d \) -print0 \
    | LC_ALL=C sort --zero-terminated > OUTPUT.txt

// test/ is the PATH
```

`OUTPUT.txt` on Ubuntu/Linux looks like this:

> test/�test/#.pdf�test/$.pdf�test/+.pdf�test/.recycle.pdf�test/0.pdf�test/1.pdf�test/9.pdf�test/A.pdf�test/Aa.pdf�test/Z.pdf�test/a.pdf�test/aA.pdf�

`OUTPUT.txt` on OS X looks like this:

> test/�test//#.pdf�test//$.pdf�test//+.pdf�test//.recycle.pdf�test//0.pdf�test//1.pdf�test//9.pdf�test//A.pdf�test//Aa.pdf�test//Z.pdf�test//a.pdf�test//aA.pdf�

OS X seems to like slashes but this makes it incomparable. how can I work around this?

Comment: Is the only difference double slashes (`//`) in OS X?

Comment: yes, thanks to LC_ALL=C, everything else is the same

Comment: A quick solution if thats the case is to pipe the output, i dont know whats wrong so i can't answer the question but i guess you could add this as a temporary solution.  `| sed 's/\/\//\//g'`. It will replace `//` with `/`. But since there might be a few `//` that you want to keep, I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: You could remove the trailing `/` from the initial `find` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `find test/` by `find test/.`; this is equivalent and should give the same output.

Alternatively, instead of using `find test/`, use `find -H test`. The option `-H` tells `find` to follow symbolic links on the command line, which is what `test/` does if `test` is a symbolic link to a directory. The only difference is that if `test` is a dangling symlink, `find test/` errors out but `find -H test` doesn't.